# How can I pass an Object from an AngularJS Service to Java using http POST JAX-RS

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jax-rs, angularjs-service

So I am building an email client that makes authorised RESTful calls (OAuth 2 & JAX-RS)to Google APIs.

I have successfully imported emails and contacts. I now wish to send an email.

I have a Controller that makes a call to a Service (successfully)

```
app.controller('ComposeController', function($scope, $cookies, ComposeService) {

    //Some test data
    var email = $cookies.email;
    $scope.to = "********@yahoo.com";
    $scope.subject = "test";
    $scope.body = "test";

    $scope.compose = function() {

        //Create an email object
        $scope.newEmail = {
                'to' : $scope.to,
                'from' : email,
                'subject' : $scope.subject,
                'body' : $scope.body
        };

        //Parse to JSON
        var emailJSON = angular.toJson($scope.newEmail);

        //Make call to ComposeService
        var response = ComposeService.compose(emailJSON).success(function(jsonData) {

            response = jsonData;
            alert(response);
        });
    }
});
```

The Service then makes a call to the Java class

```
app.factory('ComposeService', function($http) {

    var response = {};

    response.compose = function(newEmail) {

        return $http({

            method: 'POST',
            url: 'resources/composeMail/send',
            data: {
                newEmail : newEmail
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        });
    }

    return response;
});
```

Here is the class being called

```
@Path("/composeMail")
public class Compose {

    @POST
    @Path("/send")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String sendMessage(NewEmail newEmail) throws MessagingException,
            IOException {

        System.out.println("I am here");
    .....
```

And here is the NewEmail object

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class NewEmail {

    private String to;
    private String from;
    private String subject;
    private String body; 

    public NewEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String body) {
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.body = body;
    }
......
```

The Java class does not get called. I get a 400 response (bad request). If I remove 'NewEmail newEmail' from the constructor the class does get called and I see the expected output.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you need a default (no-arg) constructor with getters and setters (following Java bean naming convention) in the `NewEmail` class. Your deserializer (by default) probably doesn't know to pass constructor args to create the object

Comment: Have you tried sending the plain object unwrapped? I.e. instead of: `data: { newEmail : newEmail },`, do `data: newEmail`.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the JS code looks ok. You need to do some work in the JAX-RS side though. This is because JAX-RS doesn't know how to convert between the JSON in the request to your `NewEmail` class.

You have 2 options there:

1. Write a custom `Provider` for your `NewEmail` class. See for example [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jaxrs/).
2. Change the method parameter to accept JSON and convert it in the method. This is possibly less desirable in the long run.

Comment: If there was no provider, there would be a 415 unsupported media type. My guess is the OP already has a provider like the one from Jackson. In which case, if the JSON can't be mapped because it (by default) doesn't handle constructor arg construction, only default constructor with getters and setters. When it throws a mapping exception, that exception gets mapped to a 400. Just guess. But I'm pretty confident this is the problem.